# I am writing a SQL query to delete the data from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I am writing a SQL query where I have one table called records and in the records table we have two columns Security and Position. I want to write a query to fulfill below two queries

[image]

1. When the same security have both long and short available then we need to remove all the long and load only short.
2. When the same security have only the long position and no short position available for that then we don't want to delete any long we need to load all the long position of the same security.

Expected result :

[image]

For point 1, I have create a SQL query and it's working fine, but for point 2 I did not find the way can someone please help me.

This is the SQL which I wrote:

```
DELETE a
FROM Records a 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT [Security]
     FROM Records
     GROUP BY [Security]
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b ON a.[Security] = b.[Security]
                            AND a.position = 'Long';
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 2):

We can try finding all securities having both long and short positions, in a CTE.  Then, delete all securities which have both types of positions and also where the position is long.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Security
    FROM Records
    WHERE Position IN ('Short', 'Long')
    GROUP BY Security
    HAVING MIN(Position) <> MAX(Position)
)

DELETE
FROM Records
WHERE Position = 'Long' AND
      Security IN (SELECT Security FROM cte);
```

Comment: Hi Tim, When I tried to execute the query provided by you then it shows me "0 rows" affected. It's not working

Comment: Sorry...had a typo in there, please try again.

Answer (score 2):

You want to delete all 'Long' rows where a 'Short' row for the same security exists. Use `EXISTS` or `IN` for this.

```
delete from records
where position = 'Long'
and security in (select security from records where position = 'Short');
```

Comment: Thanks Thorsten its working....thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte as (
    select Security, count(distinct(Position)) as cnt
    from records
    group by Security
)
delete from records 
where Position = 'Long'
and Security = (select Security from cte where cnt = 2);
```

For reference check this:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e20f5769b10150663cc13a2e79cb9d53

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using an exists.

```
DELETE a
FROM Records a 
WHERE Position = 'Long'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Records b
    WHERE b.Security = a.Security
        AND b.Position = 'Short'
    );
```